# 405 MethodNotAllowed is returned instead of what is specified in ResponseStatusException()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a very simple endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/exception")
public String exception() {
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

in 2 different machines. On the first machine this code is in a very simple spring boot app and it works as it is supposed to be working - when invoked, it returns 400 BAD_REQUEST. On the second machine, I have real spring boot project, with a lot of stuff. There, instead of having BAD_REQUEST returned, i get 405 MethodNotAllowed. 
I don't even know what can be causing this behavior. Do you have any idea what is the case?

I am attaching a screenshot of the postman request that I use.

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To5qj.png)

The whole controller:

```
package com.xxx.service.max.web.controller;

import com.xxx.service.max.model.context.UserContext;
import com.xxx.service.max.services.cas.CustomerAccountService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import static com.xxx.service.max.constant.Constants.MY_ACCOUNT_X_REST;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(MY_ACCOUNT_X_REST)
public class ChangeLocaleController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChangeLocaleController.class);

    private UserContext userContext;

    private CustomerAccountService customerAccountService;

    @PostMapping("/exception")
    public String exception() {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserContext(UserContext userContext) {
        this.userContext = userContext;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerAccountService(CustomerAccountService customerAccountService) {
        this.customerAccountService = customerAccountService;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking the URL ?

Comment: I am using Postman. I have attached a screenshot of the postman request.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are sending a POST request.

> The 405 Method Not Allowed error occurs when the web server is configured in a way that does not allow you to perform a specific action for a particular URL. It's an HTTP response status code that indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.

[Source](https://kinsta.com/blog/405-method-not-allowed-error/)

If you are simply entering the URL in your browser that is a GET request and you would get a 405.

Comment: I am using Postman. I have attached a screenshot of the postman request.

Comment: What exactly should i post? This is all it is in the @Controller

Comment: I'd like to see the whole controller if possible

Comment: what does MY_ACCOUNT_X_REST evaluate to?

Comment: String MY_ACCOUNT_X_REST = "blank/rest";

Comment: When i place a breakpoint in the method, i can see that it hits it.

Comment: In postman you call /rest/exception but the var is blank/rest meaning the URL would be /blank/rest/exception

Comment: I am calling blank/rest/exception in postman. Also, as i said, the call enters the method, when i place a breakpoint.